# How to convert string Variable to json format in C#

Tags: c#, json, variables

I have a situation where I need to convert and combine 4 string variables into a single json format string. Below is the example I am trying to do.

**My 4 Variables**:

```
string SQLServerType = "SQLVM";
string ServerName = "ABCDEF";
string DatabaseName = "WhatEver";
string TriggerStatus = "Disabled";
```

How to combine values of above 4 variables in below json format?

```
{
   "SQLServerType":"SQLVM",
   "ServerName":"ABCDEF",
   "DatabaseName":"WhatEver",
   "TriggerStatus":"Disabled"
}
```

Comment: The class MyCollection isn't a collection or a list. Also, why do you want this weird object serialization, rather than just serializing each property as a string.

Comment: Also have you read the docs on JSON serialization in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: You should start your research by looking up what JSON stands for,  It is not just a fancy string *format*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @Nick Bailey for giving the link.
I figured the answer from comment from @Nick Bailey [How to write .NET objects as JSON (serialize)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#how-to-write-net-objects-as-json-serialize)

```
string SQLServerType = "SQLVM";
string ServerName = "ABCDEF";
string DatabaseName = "WhatEver";
string TriggerStatus = "Disabled";

string CombinedJsonValue = "";

var JsonSQLTriggers = new SQLTriggers
{
    SQLServerType = SQLServerType,
    ServerName = ServerName,
    DatabaseName = DatabaseName,
    TriggerStatus = TriggerStatus
};

string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonSQLTriggers);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new Dictionary<string,string> {
        { nameof(SQLServerType), SQLServerType},
        { nameof(ServerName), ServerName},
        { nameof(DatabaseName), DatabaseName},
        { nameof(TriggerStatus), TriggerStatus}
    });
```

result

```
{"SQLServerType":"SQLVM","ServerName":"ABCDEF","DatabaseName":"WhatEver","TriggerStatus":"Disabled"}
```